Data conversion in Google sheets
Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15XGzxPIvxGth4kfK4npvRD2kIcfjPKRtXXlF2RNJgLE/edit#gid=0
This is an accounting book and it is recorded on an account column and corresponds to the amount of debt and credit.
Currently, I want to convert from one column of accounts to 2 columns of accounts.
If the voucher number is 2, the corresponding account will be the inverse of column C.
If the voucher number is 3, the corresponding account will be the first account
Column G represents the account corresponding to column C.
Please help me write the formula in column G to get the desired result shown in column H.
Thank you.

You shouldn't mix up [Excel] with [Google-sheets]. Please read the tag descriptions.


You may try:
=map(B3:B,lambda(Σ,let(Λ,filter(C:C,B:B=Σ), 
          if(countif(B:B,Σ)=2,chooserows(Λ,switch(countif(B3:Σ,Σ),1,2,2,1)),
          if(countif(B3:Σ,Σ)=1,"x",chooserows(Λ,1))))))


